# nutch 1.10 input path does not exist /linkdb/current

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

When I run `nutch 1.10` with the following command, assuming that `TestCrawl2` did not previously exist and needs to be created,...

```
sudo -E bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCrawlCore2 urls/ TestCrawl2/ 20
```

I receive an error on indexing that claims:

```
Indexer: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/opt/apache-nutch-1.10/TestCrawl2/linkdb/current
```

The linkdb directory exists, but does not contain the 'current' directory. The directory is owned by root so there should be no permissions issues. Because the process exited from an error, the linkdb directory contains `.locked` and ..`locked.crc` files. If I run the command again, these lock files cause it to exit in the same place. Delete `TestCrawl2` directory, rinse, repeat.

Note that the nutch and solr installaions themselves have run previously without problems in a `TestCrawl` instance. It's just now that I'm trying a new one that I'm having problems. Any suggestions on troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems as though I have run into a version of this problem:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2041

Which is a result of the crawl script not being aware of changes to ignore_external_links  my nutch-site.xml file.

I am trying to crawl several sites and was hoping to keep my life simple by ignoring external links and leaving regex-urlfilter.txt alone (just using +.)

Now it looks like I'll have to change ignore_external_links back to false and add a regex filter for each of my urls. Hopefully I can get a nutch 1.11 release soon. It looks like this is fixed there.